# Compare two text files by certain columns and then return full line?

Tags: python

so I've tried taking a stab at this and understand the concept of what I want to do but am having trouble executing it. So basically I am comparing two text files (new1 and new2) that have 4 columns. The last column is a date column. I want to see entries in new2 that aren't in new1 (both additions and subtractions).

So let's say new1 says:

```
John 1234 AccountA 10/11/2019
Max 3456 AccountA 10/11/2019
Stuart 8769 AccountA 10/11/2019
```

new2 says:

```
John 1234 AccountA 10/12/2019
Milton 0011 AccountB 10/12/2019
```

new3 or newoutput should be:

```
- Max 3456 AccountA 10/11/2019
- Stuart 8769 AccountA 10/11/2019
+ Milton 0011 AccountB 10/12/2019
```

Notice that the first entry from each file shouldn't register as a difference even though the dates are different. I essentially want to compare the three columns of each file and then print out the full line. Code below:

```
#Open text1, read, make a set, read through the file and separate the lines by tabs, only target columns 0-3
 f1=open("new1.txt", "r")
 lines = f1.readlines()
 result=set()
 full_line = set()
 for x in lines:
     result.add(str(x.split("\t")[0:3])) #set of the lines first few columns
     full_line.add(str(x.split("\t")[0:4])) #set of lines all columns (full line)



 #Open text2, read, make a set, read through the file and separate the lines by tabs, only target columns 0-3
 f2=open("new2.txt", "r")
 lines2 = f2.readlines()
 result2=set()
 full_line2 = set()
 for x2 in lines2:
     result2.add(str(x2.split("\t")[0:3])) #set of the lines first few columns
     full_line2.add(str(x2.split("\t")[0:4])) #set of lines all columns (full line)

 newlines = set(result2).difference(set(result)) #set of new2 - set of new1 - additions to new2
 missinglines = set(result).difference(set(result2)) # set of new1 - set of new2 - subtractions from new1

 for diffs in newlines:
     print ("+ " + diffs + full_line[4])
 for missings in missinglines:
print ("- " + missings + full[line2[4]])
```

I am aware the last part of this code won't work as I can't index through a set but the main idea is there. Can someone please help out?

Comment: What about `Stuart`? Why doesn't that appear in the result with a `-`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget You're right missed that - editing.

Comment: Is the order of lines important? Can there be duplicate lines in one file which must be handled specially? If both is not the case, sets may be a good idea.

Comment: In this case the lines are pretty unique - I was thinking of creating a unique key somehow by concatenating the first 3 columns line by line and compare them that way..

Comment: If Max has two different entries (for two dates or two accounts or two -- whatever those numbers are, right after their names), would they count as two separate lines? Are lines compared as full lines, or by certain column(s)?

Comment: Think of the numbers after the names as ID numbers. Yes, if Max had two different entries with different id numbers then those would be separate lines. I essentially want to compare the first 3 columns of these lines as a unique string of sorts and when the differences are found, print the original line.

Comment: Does order matter? If new2 had new1's `Stuart` entry on line 2 (wereas new1 has the same entry on line3), would `Stuart` need to be included in the output?

Comment: Order does not matter, as long as the first 3 columns of the line in new1 matches those same 3 columns somewhere else in new2, then that can be ignored as a difference.

Comment: Are the columns separated by a single space? a tab? ...?

Comment: tab as shown by \t in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

new1, new2 = {}, {}  # let's track the lines in each file

with open('new1') as fin:
    infile = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' ')
    next(infile)
    for *key,date in infile:  # use the first three columns as the key
        new1[tuple(key)] = date  # we'll need the date later

with open('new2') as fin:
    infile = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    next(infile)
    for *key,date in infile:
        new2[tuple(key)] = date

with open('output', 'w') as outfile:
    for k in (k for k in new1 if k not in new2):  # the keys in new1, but not in new2
        outfile.write('-' + '\t'.join(list(k) + [new1[k]]) + '\n')  # add the date, write out with tabls
    for k in (k for k in new2 if k not in new1):
        outfile.write('+' + '\t'.join(list(k) + [new2[k]]) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for this - seems there is an error - last line 21

Comment: @oddtimesigs: fixed~

Answer (score 0):

You can not access set by index, this won't work `full_line[4]`.
Sets are unordered. But your problem can be solved using dictionaries.

```py
file1_lines = [l.strip() for l in open('new1.txt').readlines()]
file1_dict = {' '.join(line.split(' ')[:3]) : line for line in file1_lines}

file2_lines = [l.strip() for l in open('new2.txt').readlines()]
file2_dict = {' '.join(line.split(' ')[:3]) : line for line in file2_lines}


file1_keys = file1_dict.keys()
file2_keys = file2_dict.keys()

added = file2_keys - file1_keys
removed = file1_keys - file2_keys

for line in removed:
    print("-", file1_dict[line])
for line in added:
    print("+", file2_dict[line])
```

**Output:**

```
+ Milton 0011 AccountB 10/12/2019
- Max 3456 AccountA 10/11/2019
- Stuart 8769 AccountA 10/11/2019
```

Note: I specified the delimiter as space, not tab.
Also note that this doesn't maintain the line order.